# Conversion headache

Tags: java, xml, jpa, jaxb, schema

I'm in front of a task of converting XML nodes to JPA entities. Objects in the XML are similar to those represented by the entities, but not exactly the same. It seems there will be much of conversion code ahead of me.

XML is defined in Schema .xsd file and I'm using JAXB to generate the classes and create instances. The decision from above is not to touch the generated types. I will create converters for each of them, maybe I'll go with visitor pattern, don't know yet.

What troubles me is a situation in which someone decides to alter the .xsd file and will not update the responsible converter.

My idea is to make those converter classes maintain a static final list of fields from appropriate JAXB class that are handled in the code. Should anybody alter them in the .xsd file, some warning would be logged that some fields are not handled yet, or some handled fields don't exist anymore.

Additionally, I would like to ensure that the number of converters matches the number of JAXB generated classes. **How to do that?**

*Maybe I should somehow check in the execution time what classes can be generated from the .xsd file and compare them with the registered converters. I feel I cannot just scan classes in a specific package to check the JAXB output classes.*

*Maybe the visitor pattern could tell me what went wrong, but it would probably be a bad idea to prolong the check till the error in XML-JPA conversion happens in practice.*

Comment: If you generate classes at the time of build process, then compilation fails in case if some one changed the XSD file and for the fields which are not handled, one should notify some one who can implement the missing fields. There is no simple solution to that.

Comment: They should notify, but you never know if they will... Although, it may be true that the precautions could take me more time than it is worth.

Comment: If you want your XSD to evolve independently of your target Java classes, I's suggest to not use JAXB. Instead, you could just have your convertors use XPath expressions to extract data from the XML file at well-known locations. If the schema changes, some of paths may not be valid anymore, but XPath won't crash and you could log some warning message.

Comment: As long as if you are generating JAXB classes properly, it will generate compile time errors, for others you should write test cases o r some sort of code which does verification

Comment: xsd and entities classes are given and I have no power over them. I can only translate and it must be a 'manual' translation.

Answer (score 0):

If I get this right, you want to have entities annotated also with JAXB annotations, xsd files and create mappers xml <-> entity, right? Or there is some DTO between xml and entity?

I think you could try to create xsd files from Java classes during build.
Then xml -> Java class convertion you could do using JAXB marshaller.
And if you still need to know if number of convertes matches the number of Java classes, then I would create integration test for this. For instance I would require to keep some naming convention:
MyEntity, MyEntityMapper
Then test would go through entities (dtos?) and search for mappers.

But maybe I didn't understood your problem correctly, co please provide me with more details.

Comment: Direct xml to entity not possible. xsd is not generated.

Comment: Thanks to this you keep entity clean from JAXB annotations. So I think I would use JAXB marshaller for xml <-> DTO and create mappers for DTO <-> entity. Still integration test for ensuring mappers existence. What do you think?

Comment: Yes I want to make tests, but I need to somehow determine the full list of handled classes. They are generated during build time. I guess I will need to get more deep into JAXB, to get that list from the .xsd file by myself.

Comment: Well, I think you could just visit generated classes and compare them with mappers.

Comment: You mean visit them as files? I didn't think of it, maybe it would be a solution.

Comment: Yes, as files. Or, if it's sufficient, you may iterate through xsd files and ensure each xsd has proper mapper.